# Benchmark on different OrientDb Graphic API

Tags: orientdb

As described in orientdb API (http://www.orientdb.org/images/orientdb-api-stack.png), there are a lot of api we can use to create graphic vertex and edges. Does anybody has the benchmark on different OrientDb Graphic API?

I test in on my local, each time I insert three vertex and two edges between three vertex.

way 1 (using sql):

```
BEGIN
    LET a1 = CREATE VERTEX ip SET title = '192.168.0.1'
    LET a2 = CREATE VERTEX ip SET title = '192.168.0.2'
    CREATE EDGE r FROM a1 TO a2 SET risk_id = '111', app_id = '222', scenario_id = '333', occur_time = 'ffff'
COMMIT RETRY 1
RETURN [a1, a2]
```

way 2 (using TickerPop API like):

```
Vertex vertex1 = graph.addVertex(
    "class:" + node.getType(),
    "title", node.getValue()
);
vertex1.addEdge(
    "class:" + entry.right.getRelation(),
    (OrientVertex) vertex2,
    new Object[] {
            "risk_id", context.getRiskId(),
            "app_id", context.getAppId(),
            "scenario_id", context.getScenarioId(),
            "occur_time", context.getAckTime().getTime()
    }
)
```

It looks way 1 has high throughput. Is there any fast way to insert them via OrientDB api? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried the [OrientDB batch insert API](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/8adc978b643bbf2f92fb7d82ec7b4bd2deb7f730/graphdb/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/graph/batch/OGraphBatchInsert.java)? Please read at the JavaDoc to understand if fits your use case.

Comment: Yes, I read the document before. According to the document, it looks it is hard to fit my scenario: 1. it supports only a single vertex class and edge class, but I have a lot of vertex classes and edge classes. If I use another attribute on the Vertex to distinguish them, I don't know if it will affect the query performance? 2. "This API is designed for fast batch import of simple graphs, starting from an empty (or non existing) DB.", it actually a OLTP scenario, the data is produced every time. If my app restart, it is not a empty DB. I don't know if my understanding is correct? thanks.